# How to factorize $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How to factorize $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)+1$ ?

It's turned into the lowest power of $n$ ever possible but the question wants me to factorize it.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$n(n+3)=n^2+3n$$

and $$(n+1)(n+2)=n^2+3n+2$$

$$\implies n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=(n^2+3n)[(n^2+3n)+2]+1=[(n^2+3n)+1]^2$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ Rearrange the product into a  $\rm\color{#0a0}{\,DS} = $ difference of squares, $ $ then add $\,\color{#c00}1$

$\qquad\quad  \color{#c00}n(n\!+\!1)(n\!+\!2)(\color{#c00}{n\!+\!3})\, =\, (\underbrace{\color{#c00}{n^2\!+\!3n}}_{\Large\ x^{\phantom{c}}})(\underbrace{n^2\!+\!3n\!+\!2}_{\Large\ \ x\ +\ 2a})\,\overset{\rm\color{#0a0}{DS}} =\, (\underbrace{n^2\!+\!3n\!+\!1)^2\color{#c00}{-1}}_{\Large\ \ \ (x+a)^2\,-\ a^2}$

Answer (score 2):

Set $\dfrac{n+n+1+n+2+n+3}4=m\iff 2n+3=2m$

$\implies n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)+1=\dfrac{2n(2n+2)(2n+4)(2n+6)}{2^4}+1$

$=\dfrac{(2m-3)(2m-1)(2m+1)(2m+3)}{2^4}+1$

$=\dfrac{(4m^2-9)(4m^2-1)}{2^4}+1$

$=\dfrac{(4m^2)^2-2\cdot4m^2\cdot5+5^2}{2^4}=\dfrac{(4m^2-5)^2}{(2^2)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at the first few values, for small $n$.

Answer (score -1):

Just by running it through Wolfram, I think the simplest way to write it is $(n^2+3n+1)^2$. Many of the other ways still had a "$+1$" at the end of them.

Comment: it must be factorized. but you have a second power in your polynomial. are you sure?

Comment: Also, the question was "how to factorize...", not "what is the factorized form of...".

Comment: @BlueSky This *is* factored completely over $\Bbb Q$, but not over $\Bbb C$. You never specified which you were doing it over. The letter $n$ is suggestive of integer arguments, which is suggestive of factoring with integers only.

Comment: I think you are right. and it has no other solutions.